# Awake function issues in relation to Singleton

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

So I was looking into implementing the new Unity input system into my game by reworking my code in my PlayerController script and got stuck pretty early on.

Here is the code that causes issues:

```
private PlayerInput playerInputController;

private void Awake()
    {
        playerInputController = new PlayerInput();
    }
```

A green scribbly line appears under the 'Awake()' bit.

The code itself actually works, but it causes a lof of other issues, which makes a **bunch** of error messages appear saying:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

The error messages all lead to places where I've used lines of code like this one in other scripts, to get variables and methods from my PlayerController script:

```
if (PlayerController.instance.isGroundedPhys)
```

Lastly, here's my singleton script, since it's likely relevant, as it's connected to my PlayerController script and allows it to be accessible from other scripts:

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class Singleton<Instance> : MonoBehaviour where Instance : Singleton<Instance>
{
    public static Instance instance;

    public virtual void Awake()
    {
        if (!instance)
        {
            instance = this as Instance;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This bit is at the top of my PlayerController script to make it accessible from other scripts:

```
    public class PlayerController : Singleton<PlayerController>
{
```

I've been looking around and can't find anybody talking about similar issues. I think it's related to my singleton script, but I can't figure it out. :[

**[Edit]:**

I just found out it also gives this warning in the Unity console:

```
warning CS0114: 'PlayerController.Awake()' hides inherited member 'Singleton<PlayerController>.Awake()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
```

Comment: It is just `Awake` of one script getting called before giving chance to the `Awake` of the Script which actually initializes the `PlayerInput` variable. In my humble opinion avoid Singleton and learn a bit about SOLID principles. [Unite Austin 2017 SOLID talk link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIf3-aDTOOA). Moreover, I failed to see, any usage of `Singleton` script that you mentioned might be of relevance, in any of the snippets pasted by you.

Comment: It appears instead of calling `new PlayerInput ()`, you need to use this `Singleton <Instance >` script in some way to get the reference of  `PlayerInput` instance, which you failed to do.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think I'm not the best at collecting all of the necessary info to get the full picture.

I have a PlayerController script which the Singleton script enables to be globally accessible from any other script. The way I'm doing this is by writing out "PlayerController.instance.'whatever variable or method I need'"

This is to avoid having to drag references to the editor all the time.

I'll take a look at the link you sent, however. Thanks :)

Comment: why you need write this: playerInputController = new PlayerInput(); ?

Comment: which class implement Singleton<Instance> ?

Comment: Also, I failed to get this across.. the code I've written for implementing the input system actually succeeded to do what it was meant to do, however, it causes a bunch of error messages for everytime I've taken advantage of the singleton that makes my PlayerController globally accessible.

This is also why I thought the singleton script would be useful, as the two Awake methods might get in each other's way or something?

Comment: TimChang, I need it so I can get the values of my input, like when I press left or right arrow keys, so that I can implement it into my existing player controls.

Also, I don't fully understand your second question :o My PlayerController?
It writes out like:
public class PlayerController : Singleton<PlayerController>

Is that what you mean? :o

Comment: I updated the post to make more sense. I hope it clarifies some things.

Comment: Is `PlayerInput` extending from `Singleton <Instance>`?

Comment: I don't think so? I posted everything that's in my singleton script in the post. There's no more code in it than that.

PlayerInput is literally just the name of the Input Actions asset from Unity's new input system.

What's odd to me is that the Awake method gets green scribbly lines underneath, and my Start function is fine. It lead me to believe that the Awake function in my Singleton script has something to do with it?
Or maybe I'm mistaken. But that's all I could think of.

Comment: Just found a warning message that I added to the post as well. Maybe it can help :/

Answer (score 1):

[`PlayerInput`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput.html) is a `MonoBehaviour`!

[image]

No seriously, this is "Not Allowed" and you should actually give you an according warning in the console.

A `MonoBehaviour` "can"/should only exist attached to an according `GameObject` and always be created by the underlying `c++` framework. It's a `c#` thing that Unity can't fully prevent you from using `new` to create one.

The only valid way of creating an instance of a `MonoBehaviour` are

- `Instantiate` a prefab that has the component attached
- use `AddComponent` on an existing `GameObject`
- use the constructor of `GameObject` and pass in the according component type(s)

Or you probably rather want to use e.g. `GetComponent` or `FindObjectOfType` in order to get a reference to an already existing instance of `PlayerInput`.

---

And then the other warning means you implemented

```
public void Awake()
{
    // ...
}
```

or similar in your `PlayerController` class. The warning already tells you exactly what to rather do:

```
// Use "override" in order to not hide the already existing implementation
// of "Awake" in the base class
public override void Awake()
{
    // Make sure the base class behavior is executed
    // this will initialize the Singleton thing
    base.Awake();

    // ... your additional behavior here
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! It seems to work perfectly now without any issues! :D

About the first part of your post. Why can't you use "new" in MonoBehaviour?
Tbh, I'm not experiencing any issues with the 'PlayerInput' bit, it works like it should. I followed a tutorial on how to use the new input system, and this was how they did it.

Everything worked smoothly when I tested it out from scratch in another project as well and it also had no warnings or error messages.

Comment: @Aequus as said you *can* use `new` because this is just `c#` .. however it will lead to misbehaviour and errors. E.g. any access to the inherent properties like e.g. `gameObject`, `transform`, `name` as well as any method call like `GetComponent` etc will cause errors because it is not attached to a `GameObject` and therefore an invalid zombie instance of a component ;)